Fastest way to get databricks SQL warehouse data into a tibble in RShiny without blocking main thread?
The Problem
I'm working on an RShiny application that gets data from databricks sql warehouse when a user presses a button.
In an uncached situation using DBI it takes about 40 seconds to get the data (no problem).
When data is cached on the databricks sql warehouse however: the data is sent by databricks in 2 seconds, but still processed into a data.frame (as DBI does) after still only 40 seconds. The problem seems to be converting the format.
I came to the conclusion that the formatting is the problem using Python: If I do a simple cursor.execute in Python:

Time to get data: 3 seconds
Time to make it a pandas dataframe: 40 seconds (we get similar times) as DBI.

The fastest way I've found to get data into a tibble,is by using reticulate & polars to get the data (10 seconds on cached results).
However using reticulate blocks the R thread, so no other users are helped while waiting for the function to complete:
def get_databricks_data(
    query: str, databricks_access_token: str
) -> pl.DataFrame:
    """Use polars to read data as it turns it into a tibble faster than DBI."""
    with sql.connect(
        server_hostname="",
        http_path="",
        access_token=databricks_access_token,
    ) as connection:
        data = pl.read_database(query, connection)
    return data

result <- py$get_databricks_data(query) %>% as_tibble()
Before that I tried using R DBI, which was slow (40 seconds on cached results as i've seen). It was using the DatabricksJDBC42.jar driver.

jdbc_url <- paste0(
      "jdbc:databricks://",
      config$DATABRICKS$SERVER_HOSTNAME,
      ":443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;AuthMech=3;httpPath=",
      config$DATABRICKS$HTTP_PATH,
      ";UID=",
      config$DATABRICKS$TOKEN,
      ";PWD=",
      config$DATABRICKS$TOKEN
    )
    databricks_con <- dbConnect(drv, jdbc_url, user = "token")
  }
  data <- DBI::dbGetQuery(databricks_con, query)

I also tried to run the reticulate function that used the polars function in a future_promise. However, with multiple plans:

Multisession seems to work locally (windows) but not on Kubernetes.
Multicore does not block the main thread on Kubernetes, but not when 2 future_promises are executed at the same time
Cluster plan seems to work, but not when 2 Polar functions are executed at the same time.

The goal

Grab data using a SQL query from a Databricks SQL Warehouse in RShiny
Get it into a tibble for further processing as fast as possible
Don't lock the main RShiny thread.

It seems a bit overkill for me to spawn a Kubernetes swarm and redirect every user to their own container/pod.
